# Using simple function as a Class with OOP features

Tags: python, function, class, oop

Seeing very interesting code [here](https://mythryl.org/my-Roll-Your-Own_Objected_Oriented_Programming.html), I am trying to use Function as a Class with the following code:

```
def CF_ptrec(sname='', sage=0, sgender=''):
    name = sname
    age = sage
    gender=sgender

    def getname():          
          return name
    def setname(ssname):        
          global name; name = ssname
    def getgender():        
          return gender
    def setgender(ssgender):    
          global gender; gender = ssgender

    def getage():           
          return age
    def setage(ssage):          
        print("in setage fn; val rcd: ", ssage) # just for testing; 
        global age
        age = ssage

    def printrep():
        print("Name: ", name)
        print("Age: ", age)
        print("Gender: ", gender)
        print("===========================")

    return {        # a dictionary
    "getname":getname, "setname":setname, 
    "getage":getage, "setage":setage, 
    "getgender":getgender, "setgender":setgender, 
    "printrep": printrep }
```

I can create objects and call function to print their details:

```
# CREATE OBJECTS: 
arec = CF_ptrec("Ram", 5, "M")
brec = CF_ptrec("Tom", 15, "M")

# PRINT THEIR RECORDS: 
arec["printrep"]()
brec["printrep"]()
```

Output:

```
Name:  Ram
Age:  5
Gender:  M
===========================
Name:  Tom
Age:  15
Gender:  M
===========================
```

However, if I try to change age value of these objects, it is not working:

```
# CHANGE AGE VALUES: 
arec['setage'](25)
brec['setage'](25)

# PRINT RECORDS: 
arec["printrep"]()
brec["printrep"]()
```

Output:

```
in setage fn; val rcd:  25
in setage fn; val rcd:  25
Name:  Ram
Age:  5
Gender:  M
===========================
Name:  Tom
Age:  15
Gender:  M
===========================
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: When you use function as class, you are creating closure in fact. You can look up some topics about nonlocal and closure in Python.

Comment: While interesting as an exercise, looking at Python closures full of getters and setters looks quite anti-pattern to me. You are definitely better served by classes (and no getters and setters probably). Closures have their uses too, in simpler cases.

Comment: Can I access data (name, age, gender) of objects in above example without getters and setters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to set those values, you refer to `global` variables. The variables you really want to change aren't *global* though, they're within the scope of `CF_ptrec`. You need to use `nonlocal age` instead. Currently you're setting a *global* variable `age` but are *reading* `age` from the `CF_ptrec` scope.

Comment: So `nonlocal var` acts the same way in the inner function wrt to outer function, as `global var` behaves in a function wrt to global namespace ?

Comment: `global` always means the global scope. `nonlocal` means the closest non-global scope where that variable is defined.

Comment: okay and it just so happens that the closest non-global scope refers to the outer function, are there cases where closest non-global scope can refer to something else?

Comment: Sure. If you have nested functions within nested functions several levels deep, `nonlocal` may refer to a variable a few layers up.

Answer (score -1):

Building on @Deceze answer, here is your example, modified using the `nonlocal` keyword: ([edit]: in other words, this is the code you get when applying @Deceze answer)

```
def CF_ptrec(sname='', sage=0, sgender=''):
    name = sname
    age = sage
    gender=sgender

    def getname():          
        return name

    def setname(ssname):        
        nonlocal name
        name = ssname

    def getgender():        
        return gender

    def setgender(ssgender):    
        nonlocal gender
        gender = ssgender

    def getage():           
        return age

    def setage(ssage):          
        print("in setage fn; val rcd: ", ssage) # just for testing; 
        nonlocal age
        age = ssage

    def printrep():
        print("Name: ", name)
        print("Age: ", age)
        print("Gender: ", gender)
        print("===========================")

    return {        # a dictionary
    "getname":getname, "setname":setname, 
    "getage":getage, "setage":setage, 
    "getgender":getgender, "setgender":setgender, 
    "printrep": printrep }
```

The changes of values that failed in your code, are now taken into account and working well:

```
# CHANGE AGE VALUES: 
arec['setage'](25)
brec['setage'](25)

# PRINT RECORDS: 
arec["printrep"]()
brec["printrep"]()
```

#### output:

```
in setage fn; val rcd:  25
in setage fn; val rcd:  25
Name:  Ram
Age:  25
Gender:  M
===========================
Name:  Tom
Age:  25
Gender:  M
===========================
```

Comment: This is essentially same as other answer. This is not consistent with your high reputation.

Comment: I did not attempt to be different, as it says explicitly in introduction, it is the code you get when applying @Deceze answer! I believe it is useful to some to see the expanded code; it serves as an example.